# Desativar Case Sensitive do Filter no Angular

Tags: angularjs

Pessoal tenho um campo na pagina que serve para filtrar uma tabela, porém o filtro esta diferenciando letras maiúsculas de letras minusculas, e gostaria que não acontecesse isso, segue o código:

```
<tr ng-repeat="participante in listaCadParticipante | filter : filtro">

<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Digite aqui o texto para filtrar" ng-model="filtro" style="height:50px; />
```

Vi em outro lugar para tentar colocar `filter : filtro : false` porém não funcionou, se alguém puder me ajudar eu agradeço

Comment: adicione seu filtro na pergunta

Comment: Adicionei o input com o filtro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É só usar `:false` depois de `filtro`, a própria [documentação](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) diz isso. Na verdade, só precisa pôr `false` se quiser explicitar isto, porque ele já o padrão.

De qualquer forma, você pode criar uma função para fazer o trabalho do filtro e garantir que ela faça as comparações *case-insensitive* (veja o segundo exemplo).

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('mainController', function($scope) {
  $scope.listaCadParticipante = [{ nome: 'Jeferson' }, { nome: 'Joaquim' }];
  
  $scope.filtroCs = function(item, index, array) {
    if($scope.filtro2 == undefined)
      return true;
    
    return item.nome.toLowerCase().indexOf($scope.filtro2.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
  };
});
```

```css
table, th, td {
   border: 1px solid gray;
   margin: 10px;
}

input {
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="mainController">

  <input ng-model="filtro" type="text" />
  
  <table>
    <thead>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="participante in listaCadParticipante | filter:filtro:false">
        <td> {{ participante.nome }} </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  
  <h4>Exemplo usando uma função: </h4>
  
  <input ng-model="filtro2" type="text" />
  
  <table>
    <thead>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="participante in listaCadParticipante | filter:filtroCs">
        <td> {{ participante.nome }} </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</div>
```